# Persisting unsaved changes to untitled buffers in a session

Tags: buffers, save, sessions

Sublime Text has a killer feature I'd really like to get working in Vim. It's pretty much the only reason why I can't drop it in favor of Vim yet.

The feature is that Sublime remembers unsaved changes to files as well as untitled buffers after you quit and reopen the application. So I can pretty much close Sublime without saving anything, and when I reopen it the unsaved changes will still be there as I left them. It automatically makes regular session snapshots, which protects me against system crashes and other types of minor accidents. I've also found it a useful way of storing temporary notes without needing to save them and trash them later.

I've tried replicating this functionality in Vim, but the persisting of unsaved changes to untitled buffers seems particularly tricky. The closest I've gotten is using the [vim-session](https://github.com/xolox/vim-session) plugin, which doesn't track contents of untitled buffers. Any ideas?

*Edit: some community members have pointed out a similar issue (although  my question is more specific), but it doesn't seem to address the issue with untitled buffers not being preserved.*

Comment: The question is pretty similar, but the answer doesn't seem to address the issue where unsaved buffers aren't preserved across restarts.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?